# Outlook 2010 folder context menu not being displayed except when folder is selected

Tags: c#, contextmenu, outlook-addin

I'm customizing context menu for our Outlook AddIn and I'm using ribbon xml. That customized context menu should be displayed only on our solution's folders. Problem is, the function I specify for getVisible callback is being called only when our folders are selected, and then right-clicked. But if for example Inbox is selected and I right-click on one of our folders, that function is not being fired and I see only the default context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. I was checking the current folder, instead of current Selection. After I changed my function so it casts IRibobnControl object into Selection, and then used it's contents, everything is OK